# Virtualbox not working macos mojave

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I clicked on the Virtualbox application and it just showed the following message:

[image]

> You can't use this version of the application "VirtualBox" with this version of macOS.
>   You have "Virtualbox" 5.0.10.

What should I do?

Comment: Possibly, use a version of the application that is compatible with you OS version.

Comment: Possibly try the latest VirtualBox version 5.2.18 available [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). What is your macOS version?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use version 5.2.14 or later.  The Mojave kernel issue was fixed in 5.2.14. 
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17805

Current version is 5.2.18. Download here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Yes!  Tried installing VirtualBox-6.0.8-130520-OSX on Mojave and got error after error. Using version 5.2.14 solved the problem!  [Direct link](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.14/VirtualBox-5.2.14-123301-OSX.dmg)

Comment: Still a problem for me too: VB v6.0.8 won't install on MacOS 10.14.5.

Comment: Its a known issue, see: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=93151&start=15  You can install VB 6.0.6 or 5.2.28 on 10.14.5.   Issue is due to lack of notarization of the installer and probably won't be resolved until 6.0.10